# Counter function not working with my list

Tags: python, counter

I am trying to use the counter function to count how many times the number one or greater occur in this list but when i input the list and use the counter function i get an invalid syntax error: what am I doing wrong:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
with open('data2017.csv') as csvfile2:
    readCSV=csv.reader(csvfile2,delimiter=',')
    for column in readCSV:
        counting=(float(column[1].replace(',', ''))for column in readCSV
                  Counter(counting)
```

Part of the list:

```
0.0,
0.0,
0.6127103157173407,
0.8655878862637318,
0.9048380327925859,
0.849697796899326,
0.7777156033389772,
1.223077163931915,
0.6120854760171405,
0.24999999999999994,
0.4999999999999999,
0.4999999999999999,
0.0,
0.0,
0.0,
0.0,
0.0,
0.1127103157173406,
0.0,
0.0,
0.1127103157173406,
0.6400779180634497,
1.4472795425260436,
2.331726238093345,
2.101501690286699,
2.1444166819278596,
2.432879927387176,
2.6140920258350975,
4.696571441536932,
1.8916938572349236,
1.0573717481050304,
0.0,
1.7108297597798707,
2.6406213715837876,
1.4722723211720852,
0.02771560333897725,
0.0,
```

i get an invalid syntax error for counter

Comment: Your indentation makes no sense. Is the indentation displayed the indentation in your code? If not, please fix it. In the line that defines `counting` you probably have a right parentheses that occurs too soon. Instead of `)for column in readCSV` you probably intend `for column in readCSV)`

Comment: I am brand new to pyhton as this is a homework problem set so I appreciate any input. I have tried adjusting the indentation and parenthesis, but it still doesnt seem to make a difference

Comment: What is `Counter(counting)` supposed to *do*? You seem to be creating and then promptly discarding `Counter` objects in each pass through the loop.

Comment: Im attempting to assign column 1 with a variable to then plug in to the counter function. counting is the name i tried to give to the column

Comment: my objective is to count how many times the number 1 or greater appear in this list and I figured the counter function would be the way to go

Answer (score 1):

> my objective is to count how many times the number 1 or greater appear
>   in this list

Below (counter is holding the number you are looking for)

```
import csv
counter = 0
with open('data2017.csv') as csvfile2:
    readCSV=csv.reader(csvfile2,delimiter=',')
    for line in readCSV:
        if float(line[0]) >= 1:
            counter += 1
```

Comment: Thanks!, it printed out all numbers greater than or equal to one, when I try and count how many items are in the list it keeps printing out the length of each decimal number in each row, not total number

Comment: Thank you, i get a TypeError: csv.reader has no len() when I try that function and when i try len(column[1]) is gives me length of each number in each line

Comment: So add another counter and increment it every line